# Send email using MvcMailer from WebApi project where ViewBag is not available

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mvcmailer

I have hybrid project of ASP Web Api and angular project similar to [this one](https://github.com/kriasoft/AngularJS-SPA-Template) and I need to send emails from ApiControllers in it.

I like [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide) and I'd prefer to use that. I managed it to actually send emails. However, I'm not sure how to pass custom data to the view since I do not have access to `ViewBag` or `ViewData` in ApiController context.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hey! I'm having the same issue. Actually my email is just empty. Did you find a workaround by any chance? 
You might want to look at this: https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/issues/126

Comment: Your issue is not quite the same (and the issue you referenced does not help me). I got to the point where my email sends and it is not empty. I just can't enhance it with dynamic data at the moment. I'll write a comment here if I find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you do not have access to ViewBag/ViewData, which is probably related that you have a WebAPI context (and not MVC). But why don't you just instantiate the mailer and pass parameters?

```
[RoutePrefix("api/foo")]
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("bar")]
    public void Bar(string foo, string bar)
    {
        MyMailer myMailer = new MyMailer();
        myMailer.MyAction(foo, bar).Send();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
public class MyMailer : MailerBase, IMyMailer   
{
    public virtual MvcMailMessage MyAction(string foo, string bar)
    {
        ViewBag.Foo = foo;
        ViewBag.Bar = bar;
        // Populate ...
    }
}
```

I know it's not optimal but that's what I ended up doing and it works fine. Would that help?